# stack with array, push and pop

Tags: arrays, stack

> Consider the algorithm for the “stack-with-array” problem, namely, the algorithm
>   that implements a stack as a dynamic array. Suppose we perform 30 pushes, followed by 20 pops,
>   and then by another 20 pushes. What is the length of the array? Remember that the length of
>   the array refers to the specified length when the array is created; it does not mean the number of
>   elements stored in the array.

im slightly confused, is the answer 30? it doesn't really specify when it was created/how big

edit******

ive had a look through my notes and.

We say that
1 (Same as before) an array A is full, if the number of integers therein
is equal to its length.
2 A is sparse if the number of integers therein is equal to 1/4 of its
length (we will ensure that the length is a multiple of 4)

where m = array length

If m ≤ 4, simply keep all the elements of S in an array of length 4, where
the elements are sorted in the same order by which they were inserted.
Next, we assume that m > 4.

for Push (m ≥ 4)
Initialize an array A
0 of length 2n.
Copy all the n elements of A over to A1.
Destroy A, and replace it with A1

Pop (m ≥ 4)
Perform pop as follows:
Return the last element of A, and decrease n by 1. If A is sparse,
shrink the array as follows:
Initialize an array A1 of length 2n.
Copy all the n elements of A over to A1
Destroy A, and replace it with A1

knowing this im assuming array length is 32?

Comment: This sounds like a bit of a trick question.  After the operations, I expect 30 items in the array, but the size could be whatever you defined it as.

Comment: I guess you need to define the length to be at least ... to be able to contain all elements at any given time.

Comment: It depends on the algorithm being employed to control the dynamic array. If you share that algorithm we have a chance of answering the question. Without that information we are guessing blind.